# Android Programmatically added view repeating index

Tags: java, android, dynamic, view

Simple Question really, I'd just like to know if I add ImageViews to a linear layout in a for loop and give them all an index of 0 will that cause an error or will each new view be placed before the previous one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends.  What are you adding the `ImageView` objects to?

Comment: I'm adding them to a linearlayout

Comment: How are you adding them?  Using `ViewGroup#addView(view, position)`?

Comment: linearLayout.addView(imageView,id,LayoutParams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error; it will be placed before the previous one.

```
linearLayout.addView(view1, 0); // view1 at position 0
linearLayout.addView(view2, 0); // view1 now at position 1, view2 at position 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

1. use addView(View view), every view will be added in the ViewGroup.
2. use addView(View view, int index), only one view will be added in the ViewGroup, because of the same index.

Comment: If you add a `View` to a `ViewGroup` using one of the `addView()` methods, it will add the view and shift existing views with the same or higher index up one.  It will *not* replace the existing view at index 0.  The new position of the view that was first added will now be 1.

Comment: the second option does add all of them